# How can i return a variable in the body of the app in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to return the variable **showtitle** in to the app but i can't find the way to show into the croll view in the main return  :

```js
var keys;
const print = async () => {
    try {
        keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        keys = JSON.stringify(keys)

    } catch (e) {
        alert("errrr")
    }
    console.log(keys)
    var keymo = JSON.parse(keys)
    var keylen = Object.keys(keymo).length;
    // console.log(keylen)

    var i = 0;

    while (i < keylen) {
        // console.log(keymo[i]);
        const getitem = await AsyncStorage.getItem(keymo[i]);
        var tragetitem = JSON.parse(getitem)
        // console.log(tragetitem)
        // console.log(tragetitem.title)
        // console.log(tragetitem.note)
        //this is the variables: 
        var showtitle = tragetitem.title;
        var shownote = tragetitem.note

        i++;
    }

}
```

I want to display it into the app:
Does someone have an idea to get the variable from the function and print it in the body?

```js
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header />
        <View>
            <ScrollView>
                <View><Text>**i want to display it here**</Text></View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <Modal visible={addModal} animationType={"slide"} >
            <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-round-back" size={42} style={styles.colsemodal} color="black" onPress={showModal} />
            <Add />
        </Modal>


        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.adde} onPress={showModal}  ><AntDesign name="plus" size={29} color="white" /></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

);
```

Comment: have you heard of useState?

Comment: @AyazAlavi  i will try it now thank you.

Comment: @AyazAlavi i don't know how to do it do you have any idea??

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to import useState from 'react' then in your component create variable like below:

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

then in JSX use variable like e.g.

```
   <View><Text>{count}</Text></View>
```

Comment: it works but she still change the words a lot

Comment: you need pick which variable to show on UI and put that in useState. Only call its update method when you want to update UI.